# Azure DevOps: docker-compose over SSH normal messages interpreted as error

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, azure-devops, continuous-delivery

## docker-compose, normal messages interpreted as errors in Azure DevOps

I have Release pipeline in Azure DevOps where I'm connecting to to server trough **SSH** and running `docker-compose up` command along with others.

Problem is that normal messages are interpreted as errors so release fails even when everything was successful.

[image: errors in docker compose command even everything was successful]

After this release everything is up and running.

Does anyone know why these messages were interpreted as errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that docker writes those messages to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. In Azure DevOps pipeline in SSH task there is option **Fail on STDERR** which is checked by default. When I uncheck this option release no longer fails on this step even messages are marked as error.

What really bothers me is that now even when some real error occurs, it will be ignored. I really don't know why they designed is like this, but that's for another topic.

Links: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5296

Answer (score 2):

Before it should be fixed on Azure Devops side (imho), as a workaround the issue can be solved with redirect the STDERR and STDOUT to variable and handle the exit code of docker-compose command

You can create a bash script to handle it, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Suppress STDERR messages

OUTPUT_MESSAGE=$(sudo docker-compose up --force-recreate -d  2>&1)

#Handle exit code

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo $OUTPUT_MESSAGE
  echo "Deployed successfully"
  exit 0
else
  echo "Deployment failed" 
  echo $OUTPUT_MESSAGE
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Great job, this is a better solution