# Azure release pipeline - Build agent running SSH command returns weird error codes

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines, release

In my release pipeline, I am trying to call below command.

```
echo 'Bring down all dockers'
cd /usr/src/project
sudo docker-compose down
echo 'Setting the ownership of /usr/src/project to $(serviceuser)'
sudo chown -R $(serviceuser) /usr/src/project
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/src/project
```

Everything is getting executed fine on the remote machine. But, it reports weird responses back to the agent. as below

```
2020-05-31T04:16:18.7284676Z Bring down all dockers
2020-05-31T04:16:18.7285634Z 
2020-05-31T04:16:19.3872061Z ##[error]Stopping gateway_1   ... 
Stopping web_1         ... 
Stopping service_1          ... 
Stopping service_2 ... 

2020-05-31T04:16:19.8215312Z ##[error][13A[2K
Stopping gateway_1   ... [32mdone[0m
[13B
2020-05-31T04:16:21.0904515Z ##[error][5A[2K
Stopping service_1 ... [32mdone[0m
[5B
2020-05-31T04:16:21.8607668Z ##[error][7A[2K
Stopping service_2    ... [32mdone[0m
[7B
2020-05-31T04:16:22.9615503Z ##[error][4A[2K
Removing web_1       ... [32mdone[0m
[4B
2020-05-31T04:16:22.9665540Z ##[error][5A[2K
Removing service_1 ... [32mdone[0m
[5B
2020-05-31T04:16:22.9682527Z ##[error][11A[2K
Removing service_2          ... [32mdone[0m
[11B
2020-05-31T04:16:23.1683671Z Delete everything under  /usr/src/project/
2020-05-31T04:16:23.1684185Z 
2020-05-31T04:16:23.1993484Z Creating new folder /usr/src/project/
2020-05-31T04:16:23.1994279Z 
2020-05-31T04:16:23.2195927Z Setting the ownership of /usr/src/project to builduser
2020-05-31T04:16:23.2196728Z 
2020-05-31T04:16:23.2584025Z ##[error]Command failed with errors on remote machine.
```

So, this makes the job showing as failed. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Build Machine: RHEL 8
Service VM: RHEL 8
Azure Agenet: Self Hosted

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because docker writes those messages to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. In Azure DevOps pipeline in SSH task there is option **Fail on STDERR** which is checked by default.
You can try to uncheck this option to see if it works.

[image]

You can refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474617/azure-devops-docker-compose-over-ssh-normal-messages-interpreted-as-error) with similar issue .

Answer (score 1):

Like a workaround the issue can be solved with redirect the STDERR and STDOUT to variable and handle the exit code of a command

Example:

```
# Suppress STDERR messages,  

OUTPUT_MESSAGE=$(sudo docker-compose  up --force-recreate -d  2>&1)

#Handle exit code

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo $OUTPUT_MESSAGE
  echo "Deployed successfully"
  exit 0
else
  echo "Deployment failed" 
  echo $OUTPUT_MESSAGE
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote `handle_sdterr` function as a workaround for this issue.

```bash
handle_stderr() {
  output=$($1 2>&1)
  exit_code=$?
  if [ $exit_code -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "$output"
  else
    >&2 echo "$output"
    exit $exit_code
  fi
}

handle_stderr "docker compose pull"
handle_stderr "docker compose up --detach"
```