# Azure Pipeline SSH docker compose errors

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, azure-pipelines, stderr

When I run my Azure Pipeline job I can successfully execute this docker command via SSH. But when docker prints anything (e.g. update messages) the pipeline sees this as errors. I found out this is because docker compose prints this as STDERR and this is seen as an error in the pipeline.

I can disable the STDERR checking in the pipeline but then it still shows the errors and wont fail if their is a real error.

I can also redirect stderr to stdout in a file and this will make the pipeline errors go away. But this still won't be enough if their is a real error. Because the pipeline will pass in this scenario.

Any ways to solve this issue?

```
Successfully connected.

sudo docker-compose up -d --quiet-pull
##[error]frontend is up-to-date

##[error]mysql is up-to-date

##[error]supertoken is up-to-date

##[error]backend is up-to-date

##[error]simulator is up-to-date

##[error]Command failed with errors on remote machine.

Finishing: SSH
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474617/azure-devops-docker-compose-over-ssh-normal-messages-interpreted-as-error?rq=4